# Custom Function conditional LOGEST

Tags: excel, vba

I created a function that takes a range as an argument and attempts to perform a conditional `LOGEST` as long as the cell is not blank AND the cell does not have strike through text. However, I cannot get it to run:

```
Function CustomTrend(rng As Range) As Double

Dim TrendArr() As Variant
Dim ArrSpot As Integer
Dim count, countsq, countsum As Double
Dim LNy, Xsq, XxLNy As Double
Dim last As Integer

last = rng.End(xlDown).row

LNy = 0
Xsq = 0
XxLNy = 0
ArrSpot = 0
count = 0
countsq = 0
countsum = 0

        For i = 1 To last Step 1
            If rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And rng.Cells(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = False Then
                ArrSpot = ArrSpot + 1
                count = count + 1
                TrendArr(ArrSpot) = rng.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
        Next i

        For k = ArrSpot To 0 Step -1
            LNy = LNy + WorksheetFunction.Ln(TrendArr(ArrSpot))
            XxLNy = ArrSpot * WorksheetFunction.Ln(TrendArr(ArrSpot)) + XxLNy
            countsq = ArrSpot ^ 2 + countsq
            countsum = countsum + ArrSpot
        Next k
    CustomTrend = (count * XxLNy - countsum * LNy) / (count * countsq - countsum ^ 2)

End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by ***cannot get it to run***? How did you try to run it? What happened? Where is your data (***as text***) that can be used to try to reproduce your problem? What would you expect for output from that same data?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out on my own, please see revised code below.  As a note, I also had to add a .calculatefull into other parts of the code to make sure the function would update when used in a cell.

```
Function CustomTrend(rng As Range) As Double


Dim count, countsq, countsum As Double
Dim LNy, Xsq, XxLNy As Double

LNy = 0
Xsq = 0
XxLNy = 0
ArrSpot = 0
count = 0
countsq = 0
countsum = 0

       For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Font.Strikethrough = False Then
                count = count + 1
                countsum = countsum + count
                LNy = LNy + WorksheetFunction.Ln(cell.Value)
                XxLNy = count * WorksheetFunction.Ln(cell.Value) + XxLNy
                countsq = count ^ 2 + countsq
            End If
        Next cell

    CustomTrend = (count * XxLNy - countsum * LNy) / (count * countsq - countsum ^ 2)

End Function
```